# Can I change Git Bash default path in Eclipse Terminal?

Tags: eclipse, git-bash

I already changed GitBash default path in local.

But I failed to change GitBash default path in Eclipse Terminal.

Eclipse Terminal / Git Bash in local

[image: 1]

Is there any way to change GitBash default path in Eclipse?
I would be grateful if you let me know if there is a proper solution.

Comment: How did you already change the default path?

Comment: Actually I changed shortcut of GitBash's path by editing it's property.